# Kendo MVVM - How to Split Large VM

Tags: javascript, mvvm, requirejs, kendo-grid

I'm venturing into unfamiliar territory here, so I would love some assistance in how to best split up a large view model into separate files.  Here's a quick example of what's going on:

http://dojo.telerik.com/EdaPe

I've got a kendo tab panel that is going to have a different grid in each panel, along with different interactions/actions etc.  What I would like to do is have a separate viewmodel for each pane.  Additionally, each tab needs to have access to the stock number as that can be used to look up data in each grid.  I've already rigged up the basic viewmodels however I can already foresee that they could end up becoming quite large.

**Does anyone have a good way to split up all of the viewmodels in the example across different javascript files?**  I'm thinking that this will make it easier for multiple developers to work on different viewmodels, rather than trying to have multiple people all working on a single file... I've briefly looked at require.js however I am at a bit of a loss at how I would potentially integrate that with what I want to do.

Anyone have any thoughts?